# custom jQuery plugin to highlight the text

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm kind of new to jquery plugins. i read some articles and decided to try my hands on. the plugin i wrote highlights the elemet on hovering.
here is the code on my plugin.

```
 // file name hello.js
  (function($){

$.fn.hello=function(option){
    var opts=$.extend({},$.fn.defaults,option);

    return this.each(function(){
        $this=$(this);
        $this.hover(
        function(){$this.css({'border-bottom':opts.borderbottom,'background-color':opts.background})},
        function(){$this.css({'border-bottom':'0px','background-color':'#fff'})}); 


        })


    }
$.fn.defaults ={
    borderbottom: "1px solid #999",
    background : "#CCC"
    }

})(jQuery);
```

and here is the html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="hello.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.class1 li').hello();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="class1">
<li>SOMETEXT</li>
<li>SOMETEXT</li>
<li>SOMETEXT</li>
 <li>SOMETEXT</li>
 <li>SOMETEXT</li>
 </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and now the problem:
**i dont know what is going wrong here but the code highlights only the last li of the list.
any help will be highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out.

here is the working code.

```
       (function($){

$.fn.hello=function(option){
    var opts=$.extend({},$.fn.defaults,option);

//  /return this.each(function(){
    //  $this=$(this);
        //alert($this.toString());
    //  $this.hover(
    return this.hover(
        function(){$(this).css({'border-bottom':opts.borderbottom,'background-color':opts.background})},
        function(){$(this).css({'border-bottom':'0px','background-color':'#fff'})}); 


        //})


    }
$.fn.defaults ={
    borderbottom: "1px solid #999",
    background : "#CCC"
    }

})(jQuery);
```

this just work fine :D

Answer (score -2):

try to give every Li an id and call the function like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#li1').hello();
$('#li2').hello();
$('#li3').hello();
$('#li4').hello();
$('#li5').hello();
});
</script>
```

you could simply try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.class1 li').each(function(){hello()});
```

});

Comment: i think this will not be a good option cuz on my page there maybe several list. in that case i would have to give each li an unique id.anyway thanx for help